# simple hello world bundle (osgi) fails

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

I am trying to become familiar with the OSGI platform and I read a German book about it. I tried to follow every tutorial step to get a simple 'hello world' bundle running but it fails.
Here are the steps I've done:

1. Installed Eclipse (3.7.0)
2. Installed Equinox SDK (3.7)
3. Created a new plugin in Eclipse with target platform OSGi standard
4. Put some 'hello world' code into the start and stop-methods of the BundleActivator-class
5. Configured in 'Run' an OSGi Framework configuration with only my bundle selected and the 'org.eclipse.osgi' bundle.

Running this gives me the following message. Can anybody help me to get it running?

The error messages can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/2HKsGSsr

> osgi> !SESSION 2011-06-25 09:30:13.625
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.6.0_24 java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32,
>   NL=de_DE Command-line arguments: -dev file:C:/Documents and
>   Settings/itsme/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Hello
>   World Example/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog
>   -console
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 4 0 2011-06-25 09:30:17.609
>   !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle
>   "org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.300.v20110502 [37]" could not be
>   resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package:
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet; version="[0.0.0,6.0.0)" at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1327)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you accomplished each step of that tutorial which you are following, but [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de)'s [eclipse tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/eclipse.html) are incredibly useful.

I just tested his [Hello World OSGi tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html) (written for Eclipse 3.7) and it worked fine for me, so I recommend trying that.

Alternatively, if you insist on troubleshooting your existing project:

It sounds like you haven't got your target platform activated correctly.

Try clicking the *Validate Bundles* button in your OSGi framework run configuration (in the debug button's drop down menu, choose *Debug Configurations*) and see if that passes. If it doesn't, try unticking  *Target Platform*, and click the *Add Required Bundles* buttons, then try again.

I'm running Eclipse 3.6, and I'm able to launch a new plugin project using [this equinox 3.7 release build](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/index.php) as my target platform without any validation errors.